# React hooks: get current value from child component with no constant rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

There is counter on page. To avoid re-rendering the entire `Parent` component every second, the counter is placed in a separate `Child` component.

From time to time there is need to take current time from counter `Child` (in this example by clicking Button).

I found solution with execution `useEffect` by passing empty object as dependency.
Even though it works, I don't feel this solution is correct one.
Do you have suggestion how this code could be improved?

**Parent component:**

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [getChildValue, setGetChildValue] = useState(0);
  const [triggerChild, setTriggerChild] = useState(0); // set just to force triggering in Child

  const fooJustToTriggerChildAction = () => {
    setTriggerChild({}); // set new empty object to force useEffect in child
  };

  const handleValueFromChild = (timeFromChild) => {
    console.log('Current time from child:', timeFromChild);
  };
  
  return (
    <>
      <Child 
        handleValueFromChild={handleValueFromChild}
        triggerChild={triggerChild}
      /> 
      <Button onPress={fooJustToTriggerChildAction} >
        Click to take time
      </Button>
    </>
  );
};
```

**Child component**

```
const Child = ({
    triggerChild,
    handleValueFromChild,
  }) => {

  const [totalTime, setTotalTime] = useState(0);
  const totalTimeRef = useRef(totalTime); // useRef to handle totalTime inside useEffect

  const counter = () => {
    totalTimeRef.current = totalTimeRef.current + 1;
    setTotalTime(totalTimeRef.current);
    
    setTimeout(counter, 1000);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    counter();
  }, []); // Run time counter at first render

  useEffect(() => {
    const valueForParent = totalTimeRef.current;
    handleValueFromChild(valueForParent); // use Parent's function to pass new time
  }, [triggerChild]); // Force triggering with empty object

  return (
    <>
      <div>Total time: {totalTime}</div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Are you always gonna take the current time by button click? What is the criteria for taking the time from the child component?

Comment: @Konstantin: time would be taken by clicking button but also thought other functions. Like 
`const fooWithOtherRequirements = () => { 
/*some code*/ 
fooJustToTriggerChildAction() 
}`

Answer (score 0):

Given your set of requirements, I would do something similar, albeit with one small change.

Instead of passing an empty object (which obviously works, as {} !== {}), I would pass a boolean flag to my child, requesting to pass back the current timer value. As soon as the value is passed, I would then reset the flag to false, pass the value and wait for the next request by the parent.

**Parent component:**

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [timerNeeded, setTimerNeeded] = useState(false);

  const fooJustToTriggerChildAction = () => {
    setTimerNeeded(true);
  };

  const handleValueFromChild = (timeFromChild) => {
    console.log('Current time from child:', timeFromChild);
    setTimerNeeded(false);
  };
  
  return (
    <>
      <Child 
        handleValueFromChild={handleValueFromChild}
        timerNeeded={timerNeeded}
      /> 
      <Button onPress={fooJustToTriggerChildAction} >
        Click to take time
      </Button>
    </>
  );
};
```

**Child component**

```
const Child = ({
    timerNeeded,
    handleValueFromChild,
  }) => {

  const [totalTime, setTotalTime] = useState(0);
  const totalTimeRef = useRef(totalTime); // useRef to handle totalTime inside useEffect

  const counter = () => {
    totalTimeRef.current = totalTimeRef.current + 1;
    setTotalTime(totalTimeRef.current);
    
    setTimeout(counter, 1000);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    counter();
  }, []); // Run time counter at first render

  useEffect(() => {
    if (timerNeeded) {
      handleValueFromChild(totalTimeRef.current);
    }
}, [timerNeeded]);

  return (
    <>
      <div>Total time: {totalTime}</div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Looks better however there are two rerenders instead of one. Thanks for your thought